# Why some css font family does not work?

Tags: css, font-family

I used those css code

```css
.logo h2 {
  font-family: Pacifico, MyriadPro-Regular, AdobeInvisFont;
  font-size: 42pt;
  color: rgba(71, 71, 71, 255);
  text-align: left;
}
```

But it does not work. What should I do?

Comment: have you tried importing the font ?

Comment: Are you sure that those font are installed in your system fonts directory?

Comment: Try to import fonts, for example from google fonts

Comment: hmmm if you are using cdn url to import those fonts must to work. But if you don't do it, you need to download all those fonts and install in you computer

Comment: Also, don't forget to write `sans-serif` or `serif` after your last font as a last alternative so your site won't look completely broken, if none of the fonts are available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the font is not imported.

You have to import the font to use it.

You can import the font via Google CDN or download the font and have it in your server.

**Code to use Google CDN Font**

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
```

Just include the above code in the  section of your HTML document.

Refer https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Pacifico?selection.family=Pacifico for more options to import the font.

Refer https://fonts.google.com for more info on Google fonts.

Follow the same for all the other fonts you use.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. I have found Google Font for 'Pacifico'. Find for others if available. If they are not free and you have purchased those, add relative path of their location in @font-face rule.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Pacifico";
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico');
}

.logo h2 {
  font-family: "Pacifico", "MyriadPro-Regular", "AdobeInvisFont";
  font-size: 42pt;
  color: rgba(71, 71, 71, 255);
  text-align: left;
}
```